# How to make documentation visible with sequence diagram in Visio?

Tags: uml, visio

I have generated a sequence diagram using Microsoft Visio 2003. UML messages shown in the diagram have detailed text described in the message documentation. But I am not able to figure out the option to make it visible in the sequence diagram for someone to read it along with the message in diagram.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the object and choose "Shape Display options...".  Check "Properties" and click ok.

Comment: I can only see following for UML message properties in display option: name, stereotype, attribute types, message arguments. 
All others are greyed out. I thought others are not relevant to message and hence are greyed out. Could there be any other reason for that ?

Comment: I apologize, I used Visio 2007 to do this.  Any way you can upgrade?  Or you can use annotations, which will probably solve your problem in a better way.

Comment: Hi Lwoodyiii, Visio 2007 has option to display documentation along with UML messages ? Annotation is one good way of overcoming this problem. But this would mean redo of all text that i had put in message documentation. Other than this is there any other way ?

Comment: Sorry, afraid not.  Visio is great for quick drafty UML diagrams, but you probably want to upgrade up something like Enterprise Architect or ArgoUML for industrial strength UML diagrams.